# How do i redirect (navigate) to new url with Selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to redirect or navigate to another page in the current window in the same tab but it's not working.
Thanks in Advance.

```
url = 'https://www.nintendo.com/'
new_url = 'https://www.rockstargames.com/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps, executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)

# Do some stuff
getMeGames()

# This is not working 
driver.get(new_url)

# Do more Stuff
getMeVideos()
```

Comment: The problem is probably on "_Do some stuff_"

Comment: "Do some stuff" works fine, It has nothing to do with "driver". I tried "print('Hello world')" above the driver.get(new_url) and it works.

Comment: it seems that there is no `navigate` object for the Selenium driver in python

Answer (score 0):

Please, make sure you define the "caps"s variable in "desired_capabilities=caps", and if you do not close the driver after using it using the close() method, it still running in memory and causes some conflicts when you try to run the script again.

Below you can see your script with some changes:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome 
from time import sleep

driver = Chrome(executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')

url = 'https://www.nintendo.com/'
new_url = 'https://www.rockstargames.com/'

driver.get(url)

# Do some stuff
def getMeGames():
    pass # do nothing

# This is not working 
driver.get(new_url)

# Do more Stuff
def getMeVideos():
    pass # do nothing

# waits for 3 seconds
sleep(3)

# close the current page
driver.close()
```

Comment: I want to change the url. is there any way without ```driver.close()```?

Comment: If you do not use driver.close(), you need to finish the chromedriver.exe in the background process manually, otherwise can cause some issues.